# Boost causing errors during compilation

Tags: c++, boost, mlpack

I have recently added MLPack to my software, and I tried to compile the MLPack as coming from CMake. MLPack itself builds just fine with Visual Studio 2012, and then I wanted to integrate it into my own software.

I have not even done one line of code with it yet, just a

```
#include "../../mlpack-1.0.8/build-VS/include/mlpack/core.hpp"
```

in one of my headers. Thats all, and when I want to compile it, I get a huge list of errors, all coming from Boost 1.55, the first three errors are for example (1-6 are warnings)

```
Error   7   error C2332: 'class' : missing tag name d:\development\boost_1_55_0\boost\iterator\iterator_facade.hpp  43
Error   8   error C2011: '<unnamed-tag>' : 'enum' type redefinition d:\development\boost_1_55_0\boost\iterator\iterator_facade.hpp  43
Error   9   error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before 'constant'   d:\development\boost_1_55_0\boost\iterator\iterator_facade.hpp  43
```

The line from the iterator_facade.hpp is

```
  template <class I, class V, class TC, class R, class D> class iterator_facade;
```

What is happening here?

Comment: Usually these kinds of errors come from a missing ; at the end of a class definition in a header file (or some similar, unterminated construct in a header file). This missing ; spreads across the header file that it is missing in and the header files that are included afterwards. Because mlpack/core.hpp seems to be fine, I'm not sure whether this might be the problem.

Comment: MLPack on its own compiles fine, so I don't even know how to begin tracking this error.

Comment: Does your code include boost, or does mlpack include boost, or both? If you include boost yourself, can you give more context around the posted #include line?

Comment: No, its only MLPack that uses Boost. My code does not use Boost.

Comment: Maybe your Platform Toolset (see the project properties) in your actual code is older than what you used to compile mlpack.

Comment: Just checked, it is set to 110 (VS2012, same as MLPack)

Comment: My guess is that someone somewhere has #defined a macro named I or V or TC (most likely) or R or D. (since there's no 'constant' or 'enum' on that line. But this is just a guess.

Comment: No, I haven't used any one character class variables or similar anywhere, so that would be something Boost intern I guess.

Comment: Take a look at a preprocessed file. I guess some macro messes up the code.

Comment: Funny enough, changing the order of includes made it work... really odd behaviour.